# ERROR in Symbol TranslateDirective declared after upgrading ngx-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

In my Angular 10 Project I'm using `@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1` but after upgrading to  `"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0"` I'm getting the below error

```
ERROR in Symbol TranslateDirective declared in /Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/node_modules/@aviato/components/node_modules/@ngx-translate/core/lib/translate.directive.d.ts is not exported from @ngx-translate/core (import into /Users/a1410978/Desktop/ssr-workspace/asfc-shell/projects/asfc-web/src/app/shell/shell.component.ts)
```

I searched for this `TranslateDirective` in my project and found nothing.

What might be the issue ? please guide me

Answer (score 1):

Added `"@ngx-translate/core": ["node_modules/@ngx-translate/core"]` to tscongig.json resolved the issue